# Trouble resampling data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I'm trying to resample weather data with Pandas. The original data is in roughly 5 minute intervals. Eventually, I would like to export separate excel files with data resampled at 5 minute, 15 minute, and 1 hour intervals.

I have successfully set 'Time' column as datetime index, but when I try to resample, I keep getting "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

I have also tried importing the original excel file with converters={'TemperatureF':int...etc

```
#Open Excel File With Original Timestamps
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('IDLWeaterData_OriginalTime.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
print ('File read successfully')

# Set 'Time' Column as dataframe index
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.Time)), inplace=True)
df.drop(['Time'],axis=1)

#Resample to 5 minute intervals
clean5 = df.resample('5min').mean()
```

Any insight into what is causing this problem would be great! Thanks!

Here is a sample of the data:

```
                    TemperatureF    DewpointF   PressureIn  Humidity    HourlyPrecipIn  dailyrainin SolarRadiationWatts/m^2
2016-01-01 00:04:00 31.9    22.2    30.51   67  0.00    0.00    0
2016-01-01 00:10:00 32.2    22.5    30.52   67  0.00    0.00    0
2016-01-01 00:16:00 32.5    23.1    30.51   68  0.00    0.00    0
```

Comment: With `df.dtypes` you can see the dtype of every column in your dataframe. Apparently you don't have any numerical column.

Comment: @ayhan df.dtypes is returning all objects, with the exception of the index.

Comment: @Alexander I have eliminated all columns not containing integers (wind direction etc).

Comment: Time TemperatureF DewpointF PressureIn  \

2016-01-01 00:04:00 2016-01-01 00:04:00         31.9      22.2      30.51   

2016-01-01 00:10:00 2016-01-01 00:10:00         32.2      22.5      30.52   

2016-01-01 00:16:00 2016-01-01 00:16:00         32.5      23.1      30.51   

2016-01-01 00:22:00 2016-01-01 00:22:00         32.5      22.8      30.52

Comment: Well, at least now I'm getting a different error message... "TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]"  - is there a way to exclude the date column?

Comment: @Alexander That seems really close. It is saying that it can't convert the last column (solar radiation to float values): ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SolarRadiationWatts/m^2'

Comment: Odd. I loaded the excerpt of the data you provided into a dataframe using 'Time' as a column, then ran through the steps as you documented. I will offer the caveat that I used `df.drop(['Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)` but all things equal that shouldn't matter here. When I did run the resample it worked, of course only printing out the values of the 2016-01-01 00:10:00 entry.

Comment: @Alexander I tried dropping the last column, and I'm getting the same error with the next-to-last column.

Comment: when you ran df.dtypes you said it returned all objects, do you mean the value in the output table was object for each row (being the column names)? Mine looks like this.                                                                                Time                        object
TemperatureF               float64
DewpointF                  float64
PressureIn                 float64
Humidity                     int64
HourlyPrecipIN             float64
dailyrainin                float64
SolarRadiationWatts/m^2      int64
dtype: objec

Comment: Correct - Each row was labeled as an object

Comment: Hmm. This is tricky. I can't even replicate your error on my end, even when i force everything to be object instead of float or int. If you want to post the file somewhere I could try to sort it, but otherwise I can't do much else.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! The original text file was outputted from bs4 I've upload a copy of the original weather .txt file, the saved xlsx, and jupyter notebook to: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7L3LmgUI4rsQ1BBMGMydFZwekE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is happening with your data.

[image]

To fix it:

```
>>> df[df.Time.notnull()].set_index('Time').astype(float).resample('5min')
                 TemperatureF  DewpointF  PressureIn  Humidity  HourlyPrecipIn  

dailyrainin  SolarRadiationWatts/m^2
Time                                                                                                                    
2016-01-01 00:00:00          31.9      22.20       30.51        67               0            0                        0
2016-01-01 00:05:00           NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN             NaN          NaN                      NaN
2016-01-01 00:10:00          32.2      22.50       30.52        67               0            0                        0
2016-01-01 00:15:00          32.5      23.10       30.51        68               0            0                        0
2016-01-01 00:20:00          32.5      22.80       30.52        67               0            0                        0
...
```

Comment: Wow. So simple and clear in retrospect. Thank you for identifying the problem and for your help! To others who provided helpful suggestions, my apologies for leading anyone astray by providing an incomplete portrayal of the problem.